# How to mock & verify NumberFormatter using Mockito

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito, mobile-development

I have a `CustomFormatter` class that uses `android.icu.number.NumberFormatter` inside it. I wanna run unit test on `CustomFormatter` and verify that `NumberFormatter` was indeed called with correct values, that are calculated inside the `CustomFormatter`. I am using Mockito 5.2.1 in Kotlin 1.9.20.

I have tried two ideas denoted as **A** and **B**:

```
class CustomFormatter(
    private val numberFormatter: LocalizedNumberFormatter,
) {
    fun formatA(stuff: String): String {
        // ... some logic
        val number: Long = 10 // this is calculated
        val unit = MeasureUnit.SECOND // this is calculated
        val measure = Measure(number, unit)
        return numberFormatter
            .unitWidth(NumberFormatter.UnitWidth.FULL_NAME)
            .format(measure)
            .toString()
    }

    fun formatB(stuff: String): String {
        // ... some logic
        val number: Long = 10 // this is calculated
        val unit = MeasureUnit.SECOND // this is calculated
        return numberFormatter
            .unitWidth(NumberFormatter.UnitWidth.FULL_NAME)
            .unit(unit)
            .format(number)
            .toString()
    }
}
```

And the tests:

```
@Test
fun testA() {
    val formattedNumber = mock<FormattedNumber> {
        on { toString() } doReturn "X units"
    }
    val numberFormatter = mock<LocalizedNumberFormatter> {
        on { unitWidth(any()) } doReturn it
        on { format(any<Measure>()) } doReturn formattedNumber
    }

    val formatter = CustomFormatter(numberFormatter)
    formatter.formatA("stuff")

    verify(numberFormatter).format(Measure(10, MeasureUnit.SECOND))
}

@Test
fun testB() {
    val formattedNumber = mock<FormattedNumber> {
        on { toString() } doReturn "X units"
    }
    val numberFormatter = mock<LocalizedNumberFormatter> {
        on { unitWidth(any()) } doReturn it
        on { unit(any()) } doReturn it
        on { format(any<Long>()) } doReturn formattedNumber
        on { format(any<Number>()) } doReturn formattedNumber
    }

    val formatter = CustomFormatter(numberFormatter)
    formatter.formatB("stuff")

    verify(numberFormatter).unit(MeasureUnit.SECOND)
    verify(numberFormatter).format(10)
}
```

When doing **A** the test crashes with `RuntimeException`:

```
Method equals in android.icu.util.Measure not mocked.
```

but I don't know how to mock it.

When doing **B** the test just crashes inside `formatB` on `NullPointerException`.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/training/testing/local-tests#error

Comment: @k314159 That just changes `RuntimeException` into `NullPointerException`. I don't think this is an issue with config. I just can't find how to use Mockito this way.

Answer (score 0):

I used [instrumented tests](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/instrumented-tests) instead.

**Note:**
I'll leave the question open, because this doesn't really answer the question. But I think that if you are having this kind of problem, you really meant to use instrumented tests instead of unit tests.